# Can't pass object ID forward to another object if I don't use db.SaveChanges()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, savechanges

In my `ActionResult`, I want to submit a Job and a `Image`, and Image object must have an `JobID` but if I don't `saveChanges` first for Job object the ID doesn't go forward.

```
var jobs = new Job
{

 ID = job.ID,
 .
 .
 //blabla other attributes
}

db.Jobs.Add(jobs);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Here I create img object

```
img.JobID = jobs.ID;

db.Entry(img).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;

db.SaveChanges();
```

And here I have to `SaveChanges` on more time to save the `Image`, and I don't get any id in `JobID` if I don't `SaveChanges` after I create job object, how I can `SaveChanges` only one time? As I heard is not a good practice to have multiple `SaveChanges` in same `ActionResult`.

Comment: when you use automatic id generation, database will generate id when inserting row to database, so the solution is to use manual id, for example guid and then you can use that before saving record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try if you create correct relationship, get below as concept to apply for your issue :

```
 var jobs = new Job
 {
   ID = job.ID,
   .
   .
   Image = new Image() { ... } 
  }

  db.Jobs.Add(jobs);
  db.SaveChanges();
```